# Why is Unity applying different settings to an object copied from another?

Tags: unity, blender, import

I am trying to create some turrets, I have my Blender model which I import into Unity just fine. This model is a double turret with identical turret models for top and bottom. I have to apply a -90Z rotation to the model to ensure the turret points the correct direction when aiming at the targets. It imports fine and works as expected.

I then literally copy this file, save it with a different file name and remove a turret. So now it is just a single turret model. I then leave the settings as is change nothing. When I import to Unity, it then applies a -90X and 90Z rotation. I have changed nothing except remove a turret leaving the values the same. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst waiting for answers, I figured out that my double turret is contained within an empty game object assuming this is automatic as it is two objects where as the single turret was not. Once I put the single turret into an empty game object I was able to correct the rotation issues with the single turret.

Comment: This answer would be better if it walked through the steps of how you corrected the rotation issues using the empty game object.